# Texture only one side of face

Tags: texturing, uv, faces

So I have a vase which I have textured.
[image]

But as you can see, both the outside and the inside have the same texture, however, what I want is the outside to have the flower pattern, and the inside to have a solid color. Is there any way to do that?

PS: I am making this model for a game, not for render.

Answer (score -1):

In 3D view, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Set your selection mode to face select (mode toggle is in the upper left hand corner of the 3D viewport). Select the inside faces of the vase. Press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate then select *Separate by Selection* from the pop-up menu. It should be the default option. If so you can just left click after pressing <kbd>P</kbd>. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Object Mode*, select the separated inner surfaces and apply a new material to them.

Comment: You can apply different materials to different parts of an object, you shouldn't have to separate into a another mesh just for that.

Comment: Agreed, simply go into edit mode, select all the inside faces, in the material tab hit the + button and add a new material. Pick a color and hit apply while the faces are still selected.

Comment: I did not know that different materials could be applied in edit mode. Good to know. It's great to be a part of this community and always learning.